# C++: std::bind -> std::function

Tags: c++11, functional-programming, bind

I have several functions which receive the following type:

```
function<double(int,int,array2D<vector<double *>>*)>
```

Where `array2D` is a custom type. Further, I have a function which takes the following as arguments:

```
double ising_step_distribution(double temp,int i,int j,array2D<vector<double *>>* model)
```

Right now, in order to bind the first value, `temp`, and return a functor which has the correct signature, I am writing:

```
double temp = some_value;
function<double(int,int,array2D<vector<double *>>*)> step_func = 
    [temp](int i, int j, array2D<vector<double *>>* model){
        return ising_step_distribution(temp,i,j,model);
    }
}
```

And this works.  However, the following breaks:

```
auto step_func = 
    [temp](int i, int j, array2D<vector<double *>>* model){
        return ising_step_distribution(temp,i,j,model);
    }
}
```

With the following error:

```
candidate template ignored: 
could not match 
'function<double (int, int, array2D<vector<type-parameter-0-0 *, allocator<type-parameter-0-0 *> > > *)>' 
against 
'(lambda at /Users/cdonlan/home/mcmc/main.cpp:200:25)'
void mix_2D_model(function<double(int,int,array2D<vector<T*>>*)> step_distribution_func,...
```

And so, the code clump is ugly, obfuscative and repetitive (because I am making many of these).

---

I have been reading the documentation, and I understand that I should be able to write:

```
function<double(int,int,array2D<vector<double *>>*)> step_func = 
    bind(ising_step_distribution,temp,_1,_2,_3);
```

However, the **only** examples I have seen are for functions of type `function<void()>`. This one fails with an error:

```
// cannot cast a bind of type 
// double(&)(double,int,int,array2D<vector<double *>>*) 
// as function<double(int,int,...)
```

How do I get a visually clean bind and cast?

Comment: What error do you get with the second lambda?  Lambdas are almost always preferred to `std::bind`; I would try to get it working with the lambda version if possible.

Comment: @0x5453 ah, ok.  one sec, I will re run it

Comment: @0x5453 error is up.  Looks like it is not sure what the interior type is in the `array2D<vector<double *>>*`

Comment: The `auto step_func = ` version appears to be missing a semicolon

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce your lambda compiler error. [works fine here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o9IZsjplIDj9EOIz). Please produce a [mcve]

Comment: @AndyG perhaps this is a clang error?

Comment: @bordeo: What version of clang? What compiler flags? Use the link I provided for my demo and create a minimal example that reproduces the error, then paste that code here.

Comment: @AndyG this seems like a phishing attempt.

Comment: @bordeo: You don't need to visit Wandbox if you don't want to, but my point stands; you need to create a [mcve] or else your question is meaningless.

Comment: If Wandbox was a phishing site, so many of us would have been banned already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get a visually clean bind and cast?

One way is:

```
using F = function<double(int,int,array2D<vector<double *>>*)>;
auto step_func = 
    [temp](int i, int j, array2D<vector<double *>>* model){
        return ising_step_distribution(temp,i,j,model);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
auto step_func_2 = F(step_func);
mix_2D_model(step_func_2, ...);
```

Or:

```
mix_2D_model(F(step_func), ...);
```

Comment: awesome--looks, visually, like what I am going for in the main method.  Do you have a second to explain what using is doing here? Either way, thanks--accepted

Comment: @bordeo It uses [`functional cast expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) notation. Basically, calls `F` constructor passing the lambda into it.

Comment: It is doing a construction cast. It is a harmless cast, but you have to think about your house rules for casts. Think of "using" here as a new form of typedef to make templates easier.